# Next.js Fetch data and use same data for all component trees

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context, react-component

I have a next.js application with class components. I have three different component trees(three pages). There is no specific root directory.
I am calling an API in one of the components and it returns a JSON response.
I need to use this Json response in all three component trees(three pages). Same response. These are independent components with no common parent.
I will be navigating from 1 page to other, and along with navigation I want data to be transferred too.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: context, redux, moving state up

Comment: I tried to use context, but the providers for all three components would be different, so how would I able to use same data that was received from API response (this api is called in only one component)
Please not there is no common parent for all these three components.

Comment: Essentially, what you described looks like caching server-side data, so libraries like react-query seem to be the most appropriate choice to me. Storing that sort of API response within redux store doesn't seem to be reasonable from a performance standpoint.

Comment: These are independent components with no common parent, should I be looking at something like an eventBus?